# Will the CST-100 recharge its batteries?

Tags: iss, power, battery, cst-100

Since the CTS-100 [uses lithium-ion batteries](http://www.airspacemag.com/space/taxi-to-the-space-station-261647/?all&no-ist) to supply its electrical power, and lithium-ion batteries self-discharge over time, will the CST-100 need to recharge its batteries at the ISS?

If so how will this be accomplished, will the astronauts pass a cable through the NDS and plug in, or does the [NDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Docking_System) provide power transfer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the wiki on the NASA Docking System:

> Once mated the NDS interface can transfer power, data, commands, air, communication and in future implementations will be able to transfer water, fuel, oxidiser and pressurant as well.[[1]](http://dockingstandard.nasa.gov/Documents/AIAA_ATS_NDS-IDSS_Overview_Draft1.pdf)

So they could certainly top off their charge if they need to (assuming they have a NDS installed by the time CST-100 gets there).

According to Boeing's [Design Considerations](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/defense-space/space/ccts/docs/Space_2011_Boeing.pdf), page 3:

> The CST-100 can operate autonomously for up to 60 hours of free-flight, and is designed for Day One rendezvous with a Day Two backup opportunity. The vehicle can stay docked to a host complex for up to 210 days while provided with one kW of keep-alive power.

Comment: Officially the first add on module to a PMA, to convert it to an NDS port is due on SpaceX CRS-7 mission.  CRS-5 is Dec 16, CRS-6 is currently slated for Feb 2015, and CRS-7 for Jun 2015, so likely much before CST-100 ever launches.  (Though technically NASA requires two before a real mission (primary and backup)).